# Scraping data from Australian Open stats

Tags: r, rvest

I'd like to scrape the stats from [The official website of Australian Open](https://ausopen.com/event-stats), specifically the data from the table, using `rvest` library, however, when I use

```
read_html("https://ausopen.com/event-stats") %>% html_nodes("table")
```

It returns `{xml_nodeset (0)}`, how would I attempt to fix this? The website is a bit confusing because every data of each statistics is in one webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ton of information at https://prod-scores-api.ausopen.com/year/2021/stats which you can read with `jsonlite::fromJSON`. The difficult task is to find the relevant data that you need.

For example, to get aces and player name you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- jsonlite::fromJSON('https://prod-scores-api.ausopen.com/year/2021/stats')
aces <- bind_rows(dat$statistics$rankings[[1]]$players)

dat$players %>%
  inner_join(aces, by = c('uuid' = 'player_id')) %>%
  select(full_name, value) %>%
  arrange(-value)


#               full_name value
#1         Novak Djokovic   103
#2       Alexander Zverev    86
#3           Milos Raonic    82
#4        Daniil Medvedev    80
#5           Nick Kyrgios    69
#6       Alexander Bublik    66
#7          Reilly Opelka    61
#8            Jiri Vesely    58
#9          Andrey Rublev    57
#10          Lloyd Harris    55
#11        Aslan Karatsev    54
#12          Taylor Fritz    53
#...
#...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Where can I find the data for last year Australian Open though? I tried changing the url but it gave empty responses.

Comment: Yeah..I am not sure about that. Can you find it on the website somewhere? Maybe we'll be able to get that from that page.